# Using RPMBUILD and meson system

Tags: rpmbuild, meson-build

I have tried to make RPM packet for DPDK, latest DPDK kit uses meson build system.
I working under CentOS7.9, there is no **meson** and **ninja** packets, so I installed
meson and ninja by:
pip3 install meson
pip3 install ninja

So, at the time I see next troubles::

First run:

```
[root@sysman rpmbuild]# rpmbuild -ba SPECS/dpdk.spec
error: Failed build dependencies:
        meson is needed by dpdk-2:20.11-2.el7.x86_64
[root@sysman rpmbuild]#

[root@sysman rpmbuild]# meson -v
0.59.2
[root@sysman rpmbuild]#
```

If I comment the "**BuildRequires: meson**" :

```
[root@sysman rpmbuild]# rpmbuild -ba SPECS/dpdk.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.rMiLfX
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf dpdk-20.11
+ /usr/bin/xz -dc /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/dpdk-20.11.tar.xz
+ /usr/bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd dpdk-20.11
+ /usr/bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.DIS5o0
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd dpdk-20.11
++ echo -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fcommon
+ CFLAGS='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fcommon'
+ %meson --includedir=include/dpdk -Ddrivers_install_subdir=dpdk-pmds -Denable_docs=true -Dmachine=default --default-library=shared
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.DIS5o0: line 32: fg: no job control
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.DIS5o0 (%build)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.DIS5o0 (%build)
[root@sysman rpmbuild]#
```

Is there what I'm need to check ?

Answer (score 0):

This situation is resolved by installing meson and ninja from .RPM packacges.